# Split pdf by a page range with corresponding toc (table of contents) in final pdf. PymuPDF/fitz/pypdf2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, split, pdf-generation

I want to split a pdf book containing 800+ pages and have a table of content. Table of content is not a part of pdf pages, it appears on a pdf reader to navigate chapter or topics. Split pdf in such way that the table of contents corresponding to split pdf page range appears on the splitted pdf. How to do this? an example is this website has a similar functionality in splitting pdf which I wanted. https://www.ilovepdf.com/split_pdf

A python module fitz has a function to retrieve the table of contents

```
Document.get_toc()
Document.set_toc()
```

I got this code from chatGPT but it only splits the pdf, doesnot contain table of content.

```
import fitz

def split_pdf_with_toc(input_pdf_path, output_folder, page_ranges):
    # Open the PDF file
    pdf_document = fitz.open(input_pdf_path)

    for i, (start_page, end_page) in enumerate(page_ranges, start=1):
        # Create a new PDF for each specified page range
        chapter_pdf = fitz.open()
        chapter_pdf.insert_pdf(pdf_document, from_page=start_page - 1, to_page=end_page - 1)

        # Save the new PDF with the corresponding TOC
        output_pdf_path = f"{output_folder}/Chapter_{i}.pdf"
        chapter_pdf.save(output_pdf_path)
        chapter_pdf.close()

    # Close the original PDF
    pdf_document.close()

# Example usage
input_pdf_path = "demo/robin.pdf"
output_folder = "output"
# Specify your desired page ranges as a list of tuples
page_ranges = [(45, 81)]  # Add more tuples as needed

split_pdf_with_toc(input_pdf_path, output_folder, page_ranges)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code generated by ChatGPT is almost ***certain to fail***. So much for that.

PyMuPDF makes it really easy to read and update a TOC. The result is a list of sub-lists, which can be modified and used for update again as is.

Sub-list items have this layout `[level, title, page]` where the `page` number is 1-based in this case. The level is an integer *hierarchy* (or indentation) level.

The TOC list however does have mandatory rules:

1. the very first sub-list item ***must have level = 1***
2. A subsequent level must ***either be equal*** to the previous one or ***exactly one level higher*** (so, level 1 followed by level 3 is forbidden), or ***less*** then the predecessor.

Examples:

- levels 1, 1, 1, ... is legal
- 1, 3, ...  is illegal
- 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1 ... is legal

So, if you cut the PDF in page sections, the resulting TOC sections must first be identified (should be easy), and then be prepended by a dummy item with level 1 if the first one is not level 1.

For example, if a page range has this corresponding TOC range:

```py
[3, title, 5]
[3, title, 6]
[4, title, 6]
...
```

then you must add 2 dummy items in order to comply with the rules:

```py
[1, "dummy", 5]
[2, "dummy", 5]
[3, title, 5]
[3, title, 6]
[4, title, 6]
...
```

Of course you are free to choose whatever for "dummy".

**Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).